# Can't convert Fixnum into String - Devise/sessions Controller issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, declarative-authorization

So this is the error I see:

```
TypeError in Devise/sessionsController#create

can't convert Fixnum into String

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:21:in `set_current_user'
```

This is how application_controller.rb looks:

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all
   helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?

  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :set_current_user

  def set_xhr_flash
    flash.discard if request.xhr?
  end

  def correct_safari_and_ie_accept_headers
    ajax_request_types = ['text/javascript', 'application/json', 'text/xml']
    request.accepts.sort! { |x, y| ajax_request_types.include?(y.to_s) ? 1 : -1 } if request.xhr?
  end


  protected 

  def set_current_user
    Authorization.current_user = current_user
  end

end
```

Help!

Edit1: Per the request, here is the output of the log file.

```
    User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = 'test') LIMIT 1
Completed   in 289ms

TypeError (can't convert Fixnum into String):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:21:in `set_current_user'

Rendered /Users/marcamillion/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.2ms)
Rendered /Users/marcamillion/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (340.7ms)
Rendered /Users/marcamillion/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (350.6ms)


Started GET "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-19 17:16:18 -0500
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
nil
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 65ms (Views: 15.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-19 17:16:31 -0500
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+SYzwvqO1Kp8GhYwSA9u3plM5A/RNNRFT3wzJICXP6s=", "user"=>{"f_name"=>"First Name", "l_name"=>"Last Name", "username"=>"test", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"Email Address"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = 'test') LIMIT 1
Completed   in 199ms

TypeError (can't convert Fixnum into String):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:21:in `set_current_user'

Rendered /Users/marcamillion/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.2ms)
Rendered /Users/marcamillion/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (348.3ms)
Rendered /Users/marcamillion/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (355.7ms)
```

Anyone come up with any solutions for this?

Comment: In set_current_user, can you add `logger.info current_user.inspect` before `Authorization.current_user = current_user` and append the output in your logfile to your question?

Comment: @Brett Bender Done. See updated question.

Comment: Strange, the output of that logger call appears in SessionsController#new to be nil (which is correct, if they're not logged in there is no current user), but there is no output from that logger call in the POST request to SessionsController#create - perhaps set_current_user isn't getting called there? I would try to get some debugging output from before the error is thrown on the post request to SessionsController#create - obviously the #new action is working as you would expect. Wish I could help more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I finally found the answer. The db got corrupt. Once I dumped the entire db, deleted the db file and re-created everything - I was good to go.

*sigh*

I just hope I can figure out a way to prevent that from happening in production.

Comment: Same issue. This was hard to debug until I found your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the following is in your correct whatever_controller.rb?

```
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Answer (score 0):

did you set the database password to be a pure number? My database password was `111111` in the devlopment machine, according to the error info `"can't convert Fixnum into String"`, I guess i should change database password to be non-numeric "abcdef" and it worked!