# Ruby on Rails new installation on Ubuntu , problem getting a new app to work (TypeError) !

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

Just installed RoR on Ubuntu 10.10  and created a new app, I get the welcome page, but when I create a simple index page I get TypeError. Here is what I have done:

following instructions available at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails

Eveything looks fine no error during installation. I opted out for the built in web server to keep things simple.

I created a new app using:

```
/var/www/$ rails new mynewapp
```

and started the webserver in terminal:

```
/var/www/mynewapp/script$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-02-22 17:14:09] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-02-22 17:14:09] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23) [i686-linux]
[2011-02-22 17:14:24] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=10120 port=3000
```

I get the welcome page all right. Then I followed the tutorial at (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and created my index page:

```
/var/www/mynewapp$ rails generate controller home index
```

Then I edited the newlly created mynewapp/views/home/index.html.erb to add a bit of HTML. Then I edited mynewapp/config/routes.rb :

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

  #...
  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  root :to => "home#index"
```

Now when I browse to localhost:3000 instead of the welcome screen I get the following error on the browser:

**TypeError**

can't convert Fixnum into String

Rails.root: /var/www/mynewapp

and this appears in the terminal:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Feb 23 12:23:17 -0500 2011

TypeError (can't convert Fixnum into String):


Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.1ms)
Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (6.5ms)
```

Do you know what am I doing wrong?
Thx

Comment: You should show what you have in your `index.html.erb` edited, also try doing a `sudo gem update` to get RoR3.0.4

Comment: You should look at the trace in the browser where it starts in your application..

Comment: Have you restarted your development server since altering the routes file? If so, please post the actual stack trace you received if there's more than you posted already.

Comment: Wait, how did you get Bundler working? It requires Rubygems >= 1.3.7, and Rails requires Bundler. AFAIK, the rubygems included in Ubuntu is only 1.3.5?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there are some triubles with database. You can run "rake db:migrate --trace" and post the result, if you still have such problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the database password to be pure digit, like "111111"? My guess I should changed it to be non-numeric like "abcdef", it worked!

Similar to this: [Can't convert Fixnum into String - Devise/sessions Controller issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740742/cant-convert-fixnum-into-string-devise-sessions-controller-issue/15458691#15458691)